# Jenkins email notification is successfully sent but not received

Tags: email, jenkins

When I run test emails from the Jenkins configuration page they are reported as "successfully sent" but only sporadically arrive (sometimes after a long delay) to internal company email.  When I change the test email to send to an external (gmail) account it is immediately received.

I am using the company smtp mail server.  I am able to telnet to it from Jenkins master and successfully send internal emails that way.

Jobs notification emails never arrive even though Jenkins reports it as:

```
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: <MY EMAIL>
```

I couldn't find anything in the jenkins.log (but maybe I need to look at a different log?).  Any help with troubleshooting the root cause would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question: I overlooked the SMTP settings in manage Jenkins page for the `Extended E-Mail Notification` plugin.  It was only set for `E-Mail Notification`

Comment: The nice thing is internally they both use a lot of the same variables and property names, so if you are configuring via Groovy scripts or Configuration as Code you can almost loop over the two plugins with the same data.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I enabled 'Debug Mode' in Extended Email Notification under 'Manage Jenkins'. After enabling, I executed a job and in the build log, the Email notification verbose was printing. It seems my problem was with invalid credentials while typing password in SMTP Authentication. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your SMTP server log to see if it queued the request and ensure it isn't stuck in a queue or dead message. It will also log if a SPAM or policy issue is causing the inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dj.  It turns out I overlooked the SMTP setting in Extended E-Mail Notification.